# Is there a way to give a name to a Rscript window?

Tags: r, rscript

I launch an R script with the following code using Windows 10

```
system('"C:/Program Files/R/R-3.5.1/bin/Rscript.exe" 
"C:/Users/.../myfile.Rscript"', wait=FALSE, minimized=FALSE, invisible=FALSE)
```

I would like to give a name to the window that is opening which should be visualized in its upper bar. (See the image)

Furthermore, I'd like to know if there is a way to launch this command and prevent the window from opening above every other window on the desktop. I would like to run it in a minimized mode (I tried with the `minimized=TRUE` but it doesn't work).

[image: Rscript window]

Comment: try the function ``system2()`` instead, ``system()`` is an old function. Maybe ``minimized = TRUE`` will work. I'm quite not sure if giving a title name is possible directly in R  tho.

Comment: Are you running in Windows or Linux or something else?

Comment: @G5W I'm running Windows 10